# Problems with programs not closing that were opened by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to make a python code that takes the output of an Arduino and starts a Program when a button is pressed. When I press the button on the Arduino it starts the wanted program, but the moment I close the opened the Program it opens itself again and it does that a lot of times. Until I guess, there aren't any more "button High" actuations. Here is my code:

```
import time
import serial
import subprocess

chonk = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=1)

while True:
    dataUwU = chonk.readline()
    print(dataUwU)

    if b'1H' in dataUwU:
        subprocess.call("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
        while b'1H' in dataUwU:
            dataUwU = chonk.readline()
            print(dataUwU)
            
    if b'2H' in dataUwU:
        subprocess.call(r"C:\Users\lastname\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe")
        while b'2H' in dataUwU:
            dataUwU = chonk.readline()
            pass
```

In the Variable dataUwU saved is the State of the buttons. I dont't understand the weird behavior! Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should care about *debouncing* the button input since most of mechanical buttons (or switches) suffer static noise when you push down or push up them. Even if the button state seem to switch between high and low clearly, the actual waveform show the bounce or fluctuations in a short period as shown below.

[image]

So, I guess the Arduino transmits "the button is pressed" packet multiple times even if you pressed the button one time, triggering the subprocess call opening the program multiple times. The second and the subsequent calls may wait until the firstly opened program closed.

If it's correct, your problem can be solved by removing or handling the bounce. To remove the bounce, a capacitor should be connected in parallel with the button to filter the high-frequency noise. If you don't want like hardware, you can modify Arduino sketch to ignore the bounce and figure out the true switch state transition. Please refer to the official debounce [example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Debounce).

Edit) I'm not sure it works, but try this python code instead of modifying the Arduino sketch. You can adjust the DEBOUNCE_DELAY. The shorter the delay, the faster the response, but more vulnerable to the bounce.

```
import time
import serial
import subprocess

chonk = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=1)
t_last_changed = time.time()
last_state = None
button_state = None
DEBOUNCE_DELAY = 0.5

while True:
    dataUwU = chonk.readline()
    print(dataUwU)

    if dataUwU != last_state:
        t_last_changed = time.time()

    if(time.time() - t_last_changed > DEBOUNCE_DELAY):
        if dataUwU != button_state:
            button_state = dataUwU

            if b'1H' in dataUwU:
                subprocess.call("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
                while b'1H' in dataUwU:
                    dataUwU = chonk.readline()
                    print(dataUwU)

                    
            if b'2H' in dataUwU:
                subprocess.call(r"C:\Users\lastname\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe")
                while b'2H' in dataUwU:
                    dataUwU = chonk.readline()
                    pass
    last_state = dataUwU
```

Edit2) Even if the python code works, I recommend you to handle the bounce at Arduino because Arduino is better at handling timing-critical tasks than Python code running on your PC.